# How to get hover data(ajax) by any crawler php

Tags: php, hover, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

I am crawling one website's data. I am able to whole content on a page. But some data on page comes after hover on some icons and shown as tooltips. So I require that data also. Is it possible with any crawler.

I am using PHP and [simplehtmldom](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/) for parsing/ crawling page.

Comment: You want tp crawle dynamic data ? like ajax responces ?

Comment: Html data which will come by ajax on hover on some `<span></span>`. I want to parse that data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hover data can't be obtained by any crawlers.**

Crawlers crawl the web page and gets whole data ( HTML page source ). It's view which we can view as soon as we hit URL. Hover need mouse moving action over HTML attribute on page i.e manual action. And currently no crawlers do actions for hovering and getting that data as per my knowledge. So this is not possible to get hover data by crawlers.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to execute the javascript using a javascript interpeter (took a quick look at this http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php and it may be what you need) and then write some additional javascript code to fire the hover events on the necessary elements.

If the page is using AJAX to fill in the necessary fields, it may be easier to use a tool like Firebug to view the AJAX calls and recreate these in your code to fill in the missing DOM elements.

Another alternative is to rethink the crawler and perhaps use a browser-based crawler. This is something I don't have much experience with but I'm sure others have done this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking into [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/download/). I've used it many times and it can definitely do `onmouseover`

Comment: I need crawler to insert data in my database. It's not a crawler.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot obtain dynamic source code that requires user interaction with simple php curl. However, with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) you can achiever hover state and also grab future ajax loading of a page. It has a learning curve and you need to install it with node.js in your server see if you have rights.

With **PhantomJS** you will be able to get onmouseover or dynamic ajax content since it's a headless webkit browser that visits pages with your commands.