# Php random number total 3000

Tags: php, random, numbers

i want to generate 630 random numbers between 1 and 20. So far, so good. However, the sum of the numbers between 1 and 20 of these 630 produced should not exceed 3000. I could not write such an algorithm. Could you help?

Comment: There are a lot of unknown variables to what you are asking. Let's say you generate 200 numbers and the total adds up to 3,000, what do you expect after that? Could you just fill the rest of the numbers with 0? Are you looking for all the numbers to be non-zero? if so, I don't know how you could do that while keeping the numbers "random". What is your use case?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Given `3000 / 630 = 4,76...` - then average random number between 1-20 must be < 5, how's that going to work?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943619/get-n-random-values-between-2-numbers-having-average-x/9943816#9943816

Comment: Well it's not a "good question" as asked, could use more detail and illustrate effort, but it is an interesting question, so I'll upvote against the stream. Answered.

Comment: Q was fine IMO  ................................

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `3000 / 630 = 4.76` which is far from the *average* number between 1-20. What we can do is constrain the random numbers' ranges to accommodate this, and get a *distribution slant* with an average sum approximate to the maximum sum.

Given the required maximum average of 4.76, we can for example generate `1/4` of the random numbers as between `1-20`, and `3/4` as between `1-4` to slant the distribution:

```
function get_slanted_rands() {
        
    $rands = [];
    
    for($i = 1; $i <= 630; $i++) {
        // For every 4th iteration, get random from the full range
        $rands[] = $i % 4 === 0 
            ? mt_rand(1,20)
            : mt_rand(1,4);
    }
    
    $sum = array_sum($rands);
    
    // If the sum is over the max, recall:
    if($sum > 3000) {
        return get_slanted_rands();
    }
    // Log the average for debugging:
    $avg = round($sum / count($rands), 2);
    return compact('sum', 'avg', 'rands');
}
```

Notice that the function *checks the sum and recalls itself* on the odd occasion that the sum exceeds 3000. On a typical call, the sum 3000 isn't exceeded with the above "calibration" — since we split 1:3 in favor of the lower range. But random is random, so there's no "average" guaranteed.

Let's test-drive this contraption for 100 iterations and see what we get:

```
$test = [];
for($t = 1; $t <= 100; $t++) {
    $test[] = get_slanted_rands();
}

$sums = array_column($test, 'sum');
rsort($sums);
echo "==== SUMS ====\n" . implode(', ', $sums) . "\n\n";

$avgs = array_column($test, 'avg');
rsort($avgs);
echo "==== AVGS ====\n" . implode(', ', $avgs);
```

This yields for the following (reverse sorted), sums between 2600+ and 3000 and averages between 4.75 and 4.19. (On average, ~1:100 iterations exceeds 3000 and is recalled.)

```
==== SUMS ====
2993, 2985, 2975, 2969, 2959, 2947, 2941, 2933, 2926, 2919, 2919, 2917, 2911, 2909, 2908, 2904, 2903, 2901, 2894, 2894, 2892, 2886, 2884, 2884, 2882, 2881, 2879, 2876, 2871, 2869, 2867, 2863, 2861, 2853, 2852, 2852, 2851, 2851, 2850, 2848, 2844, 2843, 2842, 2838, 2838, 2837, 2837, 2837, 2836, 2834, 2834, 2826, 2826, 2825, 2820, 2814, 2813, 2812, 2802, 2801, 2799, 2799, 2799, 2798, 2796, 2795, 2792, 2789, 2789, 2787, 2784, 2784, 2784, 2783, 2778, 2778, 2776, 2768, 2767, 2764, 2762, 2754, 2754, 2747, 2743, 2737, 2736, 2728, 2727, 2724, 2723, 2721, 2719, 2718, 2707, 2706, 2690, 2673, 2642

==== AVGS ====
4.75, 4.74, 4.72, 4.71, 4.7, 4.68, 4.67, 4.66, 4.64, 4.63, 4.63, 4.63, 4.62, 4.62, 4.62, 4.61, 4.61, 4.6, 4.59, 4.59, 4.59, 4.58, 4.58, 4.58, 4.57, 4.57, 4.57, 4.57, 4.56, 4.55, 4.55, 4.54, 4.54, 4.53, 4.53, 4.53, 4.53, 4.53, 4.52, 4.52, 4.51, 4.51, 4.51, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.49, 4.49, 4.48, 4.48, 4.47, 4.47, 4.46, 4.45, 4.45, 4.44, 4.44, 4.44, 4.44, 4.44, 4.44, 4.43, 4.43, 4.43, 4.42, 4.42, 4.42, 4.42, 4.42, 4.41, 4.41, 4.41, 4.39, 4.39, 4.39, 4.38, 4.37, 4.37, 4.36, 4.35, 4.34, 4.34, 4.33, 4.33, 4.32, 4.32, 4.32, 4.32, 4.31, 4.3, 4.3, 4.27, 4.24, 4.19
```

You can always tweak the slanting condition if you feel it should on average be closer to 3000... Or simply add a recall condition with a "minimum sum" check and "brute force" it. But this suffices to give you the general idea: You need to generate random numbers of a limited range in proportion to what your "*average for target sum*" demands. Demo at 3v4l: https://3v4l.org/fG74X

---

Finally, a sample of the sort of distribution you get. Given as "number" => "instances" in a set of 630. It's heavily slanted to 1, 2, 3, 4 there — *and that's how it must be to meet your specs*!

```
$nums = get_slanted_rands();
$distribution = array_count_values($nums['rands']);
arsort($distribution);
print_r($distribution);

// yields:
  [3] => 143
  [4] => 125
  [2] => 125
  [1] => 110
  [8] => 13
  [9] => 12
  [18] => 12
  [19] => 10
  [11] => 9
  [5] => 8
  [17] => 8
  [14] => 7
  [12] => 7
  [10] => 7
  [16] => 7
  [6] => 7
  [15] => 6
  [7] => 6
  [20] => 5
  [13] => 3
```

Comment: You also could go the "easy way" and only generate random numbers between 1 and 4. The condition that all generated numbers are between 1 and 20 is met and the condition that the sum of 630 numbers <=3000  will also always be met. And the numbers still can be random. If there are no extra conditions (e.g. that each number between 1 and 20 must appear at least once) that is a valid solution.

Comment: @cyberbrain well that would for sure be the easy way. While technically yes 1-4 are surely between 1 and 999999999 etc., OP's spec was for "between 1 and 20", and I'm assuming he'd like to see the full range represented. Otherwise, even random numbers between 1 and 8 would still generally land under 3000 (avg. 4.5, sum 2835).

Comment: yes, because my solution is so "cheap" I didn't dare to post it as individual answer ;) It really depends on the complete requirements, are extra cycles an option, is it important to get the full range, does "should not exceed" mean "must not" or is it more of a "would be nice"?

Comment: @cyberbrain yes indeed, and I find myself wondering about OP's actual use case, why are the specs what they are. Wrote this more out of general curiosity on how to address such cases. Suppose we'll have to wait for OP to shed light on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = [];
$sumCurrent = 0;
$barrier = 3000 / 630;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 630; $i++) {
  $sumBarrier = intval($i * $barrier);
  while (true) {
    $number = random_int(1, 20);
    if ($sumCurrent + $number <= $sumBarrier) {
      break;
    }
  }
  $result[] = $number;
  $sumCurrent += $number;
}

$sum = array_sum($result);

$occurrences = array_count_values($result);
uksort($occurrences, fn($key1, $key2) => $key1 <=> $key2);

print_r($result); echo "\n";
print_r($sum); echo "\n";
print_r($occurrences); echo "\n";
```

Comment: thakyou soo much

Comment: @lukas.j while the code produces the expected results, it would add to the value of your answer if you added an explanation on _how and why it works_. To note, when I loop your approach 1K times for insight into the yields, I notice that it _hardly ever gives results with the full 1-20 spread_; mostly between 15-17 unique numbers (unique set sizes for 1K iterations: `[14] => 42 [15] => 188 [16] => 338 [17] => 337 [18] => 88 [19] => 6`). The higher the number, the more likely that it's omitted from the random set, 15-20 are frequently missing.